# Identify an address number in a string

Tags: regex

I have a list of addresses, currently quite unclean. They take the format:

```
955 - 959 Fake Street
95-99 Fake Street
4-9 M4 Ln
95 - 99 Fake Street
99 Fake Street
```

What I would like to do is split up the street name and street number. I need a regex expression that is true for

```
955 - 959
95-99
4-9
95 - 99
99
```

I currently have this:

```
^[0-9][0-9]\s*+(\s*-\s*[0-9][0-9]+)
```

which works for the two digit addresses but does not work for the three or one digit addresses.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here `\s*+` but you basically had the answer with the last part `[0-9][0-9]+` that would find 2+ digits on the end.

Maybe try this (it's more concise). This searches for 1+ digits instead of 2+

```
\d+(\s*-\s*\d+)?
```

Comment: thanks, this works well and is a bit nicer on the eyes. I gather I need a positive lookbehind. Any idea how this would look using your solution?

Comment: what do you need the positive lookbehind for?

Comment: Turns out I don't. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use braces {2,3} for 2-3 numbers - but also `*+` isn't right.

```
/^(([0-9]{1,3}\s-\s)?[0-9]{1,3})\s/
```

I nested the braces so you only want the first result from the regex.

it breaks up like this

```
([0-9]{1,3}\s-\s)?
```

first, Is there a 1-3 digit number with a space-dash-space - OPTIONAL

then.. does it end in a 1-3 digit number followed by a space.

Comment: however in my experience people also have addresses like 242b main st and 365/2 main st, depends on your data set :)

Answer (score 2):

For your example, you can do:

```
/^(\d+[-\s\d]*)\s/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7v14Fv/1/)

Explanation:

```
/^(\d+[-\s\d]*)\s/gm
 ^                      start of line
    ^                   at least 1 digit and as many digits as possible
       ^                any character of the set -, space, digit
             ^          zero or more
                ^       trailing space
                    ^   multiline for the ^ start of line assertion
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from your regex:

`^[0-9][0-9]\s*+(\s*-\s*[0-9][0-9]+)`

You got an extra white space matcher in the second block:

`^[0-9][0-9]\s*+(-\s*[0-9][0-9]+)`

I would suggest you replace `[0-9]` with `\d`

`^[\d][\d]\s*+(-\s*[\d][\d]+)`

Use a `+` instead o 2 copies of `\d` meaning at least one number:

`^[\d]+\s*+(-\s*[\d]+)`

Make the last block optional, so it matches `99 Fake Address`:

`^[\d]+\s*+(-\s*[\d]+)?`

If you know there's only going to be 1 white space, you could replace `\s*` with `\s?`:

`^[\d]+\s?(-\s?[\d]+)?`

That should match all of them :D

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be

```
In [83]: s = '955 - 959 Fake Street'

In [84]: s1 = '95-99 Fake Street'

In [85]: s2 = '95 - 99 Fake Street'

In [86]: s3 = '99 Fake Street'

In [87]: d = re.search(r'^[0-9]+[ ]*(-[ ]*[0-9]+){0,1}', s3)

In [88]: d.group()
Out[88]: '99 '

In [89]: d = re.search(r'^[0-9]+[ ]*(-[ ]*[0-9]+){0,1}', s2)

In [90]: d.group()
Out[90]: '95 - 99'

In [91]: d = re.search(r'^[0-9]+[ ]*(-[ ]*[0-9]+){0,1}', s1)

In [92]: d.group()
Out[92]: '95-99'

In [93]: d = re.search(r'^[0-9]+[ ]*(-[ ]*[0-9]+){0,1}', s)

In [94]: d.group()
Out[94]: '955 - 959'
```

the character set `0-9` cab be represented by `\d` like this

```
d = re.search(r'^[\d]+[ ]*(-[ ]*[\d]+){0,1}', s)
```

Here, in all the examples, we are searching at the beginning of the string, for a sequence of at least one digit followed by zero or more spaces and optionally followed by at most one sequence of only one `-` symbol followed by zero or more spaces and at least one or more digits.